# Tick checkbox via javascript console by lable names

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, console

I would like to check boxes via javascript.

The thing is I have a task to check more then 300 checkboxes whith specific names.

I can check one box, or check all boxes... but how to check specific boxes?

Here is an example:

```
<li id="s1" class="city-select">
    <input name="rid" id="r1" value="1" type="checkbox">
    <label for="r1" id="l1">Paris</label>
</li>
<li id="s1" class="city-select">
    <input name="rid" id="r2" value="2" type="checkbox">
    <label for="r2" id="l2">Plovdiv</label>
</li>
<li id="s1" class="city-select">
    <input name="rid" id="r3" value="3" type="checkbox">
    <label for="r3" id="l3">Berlin</label>
</li>
```

I would like to tick only "Berlin" and "Paris" - here is what I'm using to tick all:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'),function(el){el.checked=true});
```

And here is what am I trying to type:

```
$("lable:contains('paris, berlin')").prev().find('input').addAttr("checked");
```

Comment: `$(".city-select label").filter(":contains('Paris'), :contains('berlin')").prev('input').prop("checked", true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong selector to target checkboxes. You need to use:

```
$("label:contains(Paris),label:contains(Berlin)").prev().prop("checked",true);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52hksxte/)**

**Update:**

```
var cities = ["Paris","Berlin"];
 $("label:contains('" + cities.join("'),label:contains('") + "')").prev().prop("checked",true);
```

**[Working Fiddle for update](http://jsfiddle.net/8kh011g9/)**

Comment: Milind it does work! Thank you, but can you add a shorter code for 300 cities?

Comment: @Alfonso make it a function that accept an argument - or use `.foreach`.  How are the 300 cities defined?

Comment: @Alfonso So it doesn't have to be "label:contains(city1),label:contains(city2),label:contains(city3),label:contains(city4),label:contains(city5),..."

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your use of `prev` should be `parent` or `closest`.

So you take the current label, go up to the container, then down to the checkbox.

If you use `prev` then you restrict how much you can change the html (eg if you add a div wrapper around the label in the future, you'll have to change all your code).

given:

```
<li id="s1" class="city-select">
    <input name="rid" id="r3" value="3" type="checkbox">
    <label for="r3" id="l3">Berlin</label>
</li>
```

then use

```
$("label:contains(Paris),label:contains(Berlin)")
    .closest("li")
    .find(":checkbox")
    .prop("checked",true);
```

More info at the API documentation: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

---

> How to use this for 300 cities?

This depends on how they are stored.  If it's a comma separated list (Paris,Berlin) then split into an array first, if it's json, then convert to an array first...(see the pattern?)

```
var citiesList = "Paris,Berlin".split(",");

$(citiesList).each(function() {
    $("label:contains(" + this + ")")
        .closest("li")
        .find(":checkbox")
        .prop("checked",true);
});
```